# Is it possible to embed Wordpress plugin within Razor view?

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I see a lot of materials on running Wordpress on .NET Core, but what I try to find is it possible to embed/host Wordpress plugin within Razor view.

Is it possible to accomplish?

Comment: So what you want is just showing the static blog page or showing the blog page you can interact with?